# Python subprocess.Popen to create a new directory

Tags: python

I know that I can create a new directory with the os module. But I was trying to create a new directory with the subprocess module as follows:

```
p=subprocess.Popen("mkdir extractions", shell=True)
os.chdir("extractions")
```

When the script executes, I notice that the directory *extractions* is created but the next os.chdir call fails saying the directory *extractions* does not exist. I know that I am missing something in terms of using subprocess that makes the next line unaware of the directory created. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to call `p.wait()` to wait for the mkdir to complete, before calling os.chdir.  Or even better, use `(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()`, and check the result.

Comment: Note that if you want p.communicate() to capture (stdout, stderr), you need to use stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE as arguments to Popen.

Comment: Can you tell me what does '(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()' does?

Comment: If you use Popen.communicate("mkdir extractions", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE), then p.communicate() will call mkdir, and return a 2-ple, (stdout, stderr).  stdout contains the standard output - i.e. the normal output to the terminal, which for mkdir is probably an empty string.  stderr is standard error - i.e. any warnings or error messages, if the command didn't complete successfully, for example if you didn't have permission to create the directory, or the directory already existed

Comment: Sorry "call mkdir" was probably not the right phrase.  It's already been called by Popen, but since you told it to pipe the output back to the script, the output is waiting to "communicate" with you.  You could do the same to pass input to the process using stdin=subprocess.PIPE.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use os.mkdir("extractions")?
You could even use subprocess.call("mkdir extractions")
Both of those methods will work
After Popen, you have to do something like communicate()

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('mkdir extractions', shell=True)
p1.communicate()
```

However, this is the same as just using subprocess.call("mkdir extractions", shell=True).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> p=subprocess.Popen("mkdir extractions", shell=True)
>>> os.chdir("extractions")
```

This worked for me (on OSX).  What OS are you running?  Have you tried os.popen?

Comment: If you did it in the interpreter, then it's because of the delay between the last two commands.  In a script, the os.chdir will be called before the mkdir process completes

Comment: Ahh got it! Anywork around for these kind of situations? Is it possible to wait for the subprocess which creates the new directory to  terminate before we move on to the next line?

Comment: Yes, p.wait() will do exactly that, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster to call `os.mkdir`, and—while the difference is unlikely to actually have any noticeable effect on your system—you are generating the overhead of creating a whole new process and running a whole separate program, and then (assuming you take the advice of any of the other [correct] answers) waiting for it to notify to tell you that it's finished instead of just calling a function in the kernel.